# C++ вернуть из фабричного метода ссылку на базовый класс как в Java

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм

Читаю книгу о TDD на примере Java, а сам пишу на C++. Возникла проблема в том, что в C++ полиморфизм реализован немного по-другому. Вот пример:

```
class Dollar;

class Money
{
public:
    static Dollar dollar(int amount);
protected:
    int amount;
};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public:
    Dollar(int amount);
    Dollar times(int value) const;
    bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const;
};
```

Здесь метод Dollar dollar(int amount) нужно изменить на Money dollar(int amount). В книге используется Java, поэтому возвращаются ссылки, и из-за этого полиморфизм работает легко. В C++ так дословно переписать этот код нельзя. А как это можно сделать?

Можно возвращать указатель, но тогда надо за забыть вызывать delete. Использовать shared_ptr? Рассматриваю такую возможность, однако злоупотребление shared_ptr приводит к замедлению из-за синхронизаций.

Какие лучшие практики есть для данной ситуации?

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
#include <memory>

using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;


class Dollar;

class Money
{
public:
    static shared_ptr<Money *> dollar(int amount);
protected:
    int amount;
};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public:
    Dollar(int amount);
    Dollar times(int value) const;
    bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const;
};

shared_ptr<Money *> Money::dollar(int amount)
{
    return make_shared<Dollar>(amount);
}

Dollar::Dollar(int amount)
{
    this->amount = amount;
}

Dollar Dollar::times(int value) const
{
    return Dollar(amount * value);
}

bool Dollar::operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const
{
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

но получаю ошибку:

> return: невозможно преобразовать "std::shared_ptr" в
>   "std::shared_ptr"

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно в чем проблема в первом примере. Этот код валиден, главное определение функции static Dollar dollar(...) пиши после полного определенения класса Dollar.

В примере с shred_ptr, замени `shared_ptr<Money *> Money::dollar(int amount)` на `shared_ptr<Money> Money::dollar(int amount)`

UPD: Если у тебя академический интерес, то shared_ptr это нормально. Дефакто объекты в Java это shared_ptr. Если практический интерес, то самое наследование Dollar от Money странное, тут лучше подойдет шаблонное программирование.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dollar;

class Money
{
public:
    Money(int amount):amount(amount){};
    static Dollar dollar(int amount)
protected:
    int amount;
};

class Dollar : public Money
{
public:
    Dollar(int amount):Money(amount){}
    //Dollar times(int value) const;
    //bool operator==(const Dollar& dollar) const;
};

Dollar Money::dollar(int amount)
{
    return Dollar(amount);
}

int main()
{
    Dollar d = Money::dollar(5);
}
```

Как [видите](https://ideone.com/csd8CW), все работает. Непонятно, почему `Money` использует `Dollar` (само наследование вопросов не вызывает - доллар - это деньги :)).

Comment: Функция dollar должна воозвращать доллар, но как ссылку на Money. Это нужно для того, чтобы сигнатура двух методов dollar() и franc() была универсальна.